# Regular expression to find in which column a string exists

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to determine in which column the name "Phone" appears, by checking the HTML of a web page.
The string in which I am doing the search looks like this :

```
<tr class="C1">
<td>Name</td>
<td>Address</td>
...
...   < some more columns, but their number is not fixed >
...
<td>Phone</td>
...
...    <more columns>
...
</tr>
```

Is it possible to determine using regular expressions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the viewpoint of theoretical computer science: It is not possible, since tables could be nested; and regular expressions generally cannot cope with nested structures (you need a Typ-2-Grammer (Chomsky-Hierarchy), i.e. a Parser, to analyse the structure of a html-Text, it's not Typ-3, i.e. regular).

From a practical viewpoint, however, if you assume, that the tables are not nested, you could use a RegEx to extract table rows (something like `<tr (?!</tr>)*</tr>`), match the entries afterwards (something like `<td (?!</td>)*</td>`) to produce a List of columns and search that list for an Entry containing the string `"Phone"`....

Answer (score 1):

Tough task. I'm referring you to various posts that explain why HTML parsing using RegEx is (virtually) imposibble:

1. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/290343
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/290343